# what are exfat disk file name limitations?

Tags: copy, charset, exfat

Have lots of failures copying my disk to another, exFAT disk.
Specifically, file names with ':', '|' chars did not get through.
What is the allowed charset?
Is there a program to solve the issue, like changing the illegal chars to '.'?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution (works for me) is to rename all the original files replacing the illegal chars, e.g.

```bash
find . -name "*[\:\|]*" -execdir rename -v 's/[\:\|]/./g' '{}' \+
```

Note there are [multiple incompatible versions of the `rename` command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956010/whats-the-difference-between-the-different-rename-commands), you might need to use `prename` or `perl-rename`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft's spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/exfat-specification#table-35-invalid-filename-characters) there are nine illegal printable characters in exFAT filenames, `"*/:<>?\|`, along with all 32 nonprinting control codes like you'd probably expect.

On Linux you can verify these with a little toy filesystem:

```
mkdir exfat-mnt
dd if=/dev/zero of=exfat.dat bs=1M count=32
mkfs.exfat exfat.dat
sudo mount -o loop,users,fmask=000,dmask=000,users exfat.dat exfat-mnt
```

For example:

```
$ touch exfat-mnt/file # works
$ touch exfat-mnt/'"'  # won't work
touch: cannot touch 'exfat-mnt/"': Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but in response to the title question, the invalid filename characters are /:*?"|.